# Hide Element on Load, Appear on Hover with Mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that hides/shows child elements with `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`, but the child elements appear when the page loads.

I'd like it so the elements don't appear when the page loads but only on `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`.

How would I accomplish this with my code below?

```
        $('.side-nav>li.has-flyout', this).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
            if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
                $('.side-nav').find('.flyout').hide();
                $(this).children('.flyout').show();
            }
            if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
                var flyout = $(this).children('.flyout'),
                    inputs = flyout.find('input'),
                    hasFocus = function(inputs) {
                        var focus;
                        if (inputs.length > 0) {
                            inputs.each(function() {
                                if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
                                    focus = true;
                                }
                            });
                            return focus;
                        }
                        return false;
                    };
                if (!hasFocus(inputs)) {
                    $(this).children('.flyout').hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

Doing just `$('.side-nav>li.has-flyout').hide();` obviously hides the whole nav item. FWIW I'm using Foundation 5's framework.

Comment: `$('.side-nav>li.has-flyout').hide();` doesn't work because those are not the elements you're hiding or showing while mousing around, but their children with the class `flyout`. Why not `$('.side-nav>li.has-flyout').children('.flyout').hide();` ?

Comment: That does it! Though, the content immediately appears, then disappears, when the page loads (rather than hide completely). Not ideal, but certainly serviceable

Comment: Just do it in CSS first. See my answer

Comment: Was *just* about to write that your answer allowed me to target the specific class in the css, and that way worked best, before your two comments. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideal: all your initial styles (like `display: none`) which is what `.hide()` does should be written in your stylesheet.

```
/* css */
.side-nav > li.has-flyout .flyout {
  display: none;
}
```

Less ideal:

```
// JavaScript
$('.side-nav>li.has-flyout').children('.flyout').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Through CSS, if your sub element list has class e.g. `.sub-menu`

then just add css

```
.sub-menu { display: none; }
```